# Authorization pop-up requested by http://localhost:51675 every time I run Firefox

Tags: firefox, authentication

Using Ubuntu 10.04.
Whenever I run Firefox I get a pop up requesting authorisation.
It says

'a user name and password are being requested by http://localhost:51675. The site says "server"

I have tried all passwords I know and nothing is accepted. If I click 'cancel' it disappears but re-appears after about 5 minutes. This whole 'experience' is accompanied by a great deal of hard disc activity.

- [List of extensions](http://paste.ubuntu.com/566455/)

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Can you dump your Firefox extensions and plugins using `http://www.lekensteyn.nl/firefox-debug-list.html` (copy & paste the contents from the textfield in your answer or on http://paste.ubuntu.com)? Are there any open tabs when this problem occurs?

Comment: It's never a good idea to type in your commonly used passwords into boxes you've never seen before.

Comment: Some googling says, that port 51675 is used by the JPDA debugger, whatever it is. Maybe it's helpfull. Do you do any development?

Comment: not doing any development

Comment: @Lekensteyn dump posted on paste.ubuntu.com. Occurs whatever tabs are open, one or many...even just this page!

Comment: Great, can you now add your pastebin link here? We do not know what pastebin belongs to you :D

Comment: @Lekensteyn Sorry! errr what is my pastebin link? How do I get that?

Comment: Well, after you've submitted the form, you should copy the URL which should look like http://paste.ubuntu.com/566454/.

Comment: @Lekensteyn sorry to be such an idiot! http://paste.ubuntu.com/566455/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you've installed Firefox using the Software center (or apt-get/aptitude, but not from untrusted sources).

Your problem looks similar to the one as described on http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1299957. I suspect that `Bindwood 1.0.4` has something to do with this. Try disabling this add-on, and restart Firefox.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for your help. Would never have got list like that or known what to do without your aid. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Port 51675? On localhost? Hmmm. My ideas:

1. You have some kind of proxy software running on your machine.
2. You have installed some kind of extension for firefox which causes it.
3. Some malicious stuff on your machine :(

Try to disable extensions (all of them) and see if this behaviour disappears or not. If yes, it was an extension which caused it.

Meanwhile, you can query what kind of stuff binds to the 51675 tcp port on localhost. In terminal issue the command like this: `sudo netstat -nap | fgrep :51675`

If there is some result, you can know what program runs on your computer which can accessable via localhost:51675

Also as others pointed out: it's not a good idea to enter your password if you don't know or you are not sure what/who ask that and why. It can be phishing too (password stealing with making the user think that it's a legitimate login dialog/whatever even if it's not). Hopefully it's not that case, but it's *always* nice to mention this warning :)

Comment: 1896/beam.smp     4541/firefox-bin  1947/python   4533/sh

Comment: Hmmm those are the pids and process names. It would be the best if you can check these out in gnome system monitor (for sure other tools are OK too, even CLI if it's OK for you): what is the process hierarchy, and full command line especially for python and sh. Also I am still interested if these things go away if you disable all of your extensions ....

Comment: Ah, and I forgot to mention about netstat: what is interesting is line which also contain the LISTEN word before the pid/process info.

Comment: disabled extensions one by one. When I disabled Bindwood 1.0.4 the problem stopped! Checking back with netstat: LISTEN came before firefox-bin. ran it again and no firefox-bin! It now appears before 1896/beam.smp. I believe the problem is solved!